# Is it secure to use multiple admin

Tags: solidity, remix, security

im trying to do multiple admin system in my solidity and here is example

```
//SPDX-License-Identif`ier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.15;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MultipleAdmin{

  modifier onlyAdmin {
    require(isAdmin[msg.sender] == true, 'This method can call only admin');
    _;
  }

  mapping(address => bool) public isAdmin;

  function addAdmin(address _admin) public onlyOwner{
      require(isAdmin[_admin] == false, 'This address already admin');
      isAdmin[_admin] = true;
  }

  function removeAdmin(address _admin) public onlyOwner{
      require(isAdmin[_admin] == true, 'This address is not in admin list');
      isAdmin[_admin] = false;
  }

  function doSometh() public onlyAdmin{
      doSomething
  }
}
```

is it secure to use like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to allow the contract `owner` access to control who is an admin and who is not, and then allow the admins to have special permission to use functions marked `onlyAdmin`, then your example implementation looks correct.

Also, if you want to use an already existing contract that may fit your needs, you could try using [Open Zeppelin's `accessControl` contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol):

```js
abstract contract AccessControl is Context, IAccessControl, ERC165 {
    struct RoleData {
        mapping(address account => bool) hasRole;
        bytes32 adminRole;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 role => RoleData) private _roles;

    bytes32 public constant DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE = 0x00;

    modifier onlyRole(bytes32 role) {
        _checkRole(role);
        _;
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
        return interfaceId == type(IAccessControl).interfaceId || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    function hasRole(bytes32 role, address account) public view virtual returns (bool) {
        return _roles[role].hasRole[account];
    }

    function _checkRole(bytes32 role) internal view virtual {
        _checkRole(role, _msgSender());
    }

    function _checkRole(bytes32 role, address account) internal view virtual {
        if (!hasRole(role, account)) {
            revert AccessControlUnauthorizedAccount(account, role);
        }
    }

    function getRoleAdmin(bytes32 role) public view virtual returns (bytes32) {
        return _roles[role].adminRole;
    }

    function grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) public virtual onlyRole(getRoleAdmin(role)) {
        _grantRole(role, account);
    }

    function revokeRole(bytes32 role, address account) public virtual onlyRole(getRoleAdmin(role)) {
        _revokeRole(role, account);
    }

    function renounceRole(bytes32 role, address callerConfirmation) public virtual {
        if (callerConfirmation != _msgSender()) {
            revert AccessControlBadConfirmation();
        }

        _revokeRole(role, callerConfirmation);
    }

    function _setRoleAdmin(bytes32 role, bytes32 adminRole) internal virtual {
        bytes32 previousAdminRole = getRoleAdmin(role);
        _roles[role].adminRole = adminRole;
        emit RoleAdminChanged(role, previousAdminRole, adminRole);
    }

    function _grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) internal virtual returns (bool) {
        if (!hasRole(role, account)) {
            _roles[role].hasRole[account] = true;
            emit RoleGranted(role, account, _msgSender());
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function _revokeRole(bytes32 role, address account) internal virtual returns (bool) {
        if (hasRole(role, account)) {
            _roles[role].hasRole[account] = false;
            emit RoleRevoked(role, account, _msgSender());
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Restricting a function to only a certain role would look like this:

```js
function foo() public {
    require(hasRole(MY_ROLE, msg.sender));
      ...
  }
```

or with the modifier:

```js
function foo() public onlyRole(MY_ROLE) {
      ...
  }
```